# Possible to list all PHP classes and their methods and properties?

Tags: php, oop

I'm making the leap to OOP with my PHP. Is there a way to list all active classes and their methods and properties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[Complete list of similar functions :)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.classobj.php)**

**Quick Look:**

```
get_declared_classes() // gives you all declared classes
get_class_methods() // gives you all methods of class
get_class_vars() // gives you properties of the class
get_object_vars() // gives you propertis of an object
get_parent_class()  // gives you parent class of the current class
```

Answer (score 4):

Also, you might be interested in the [Reflection API offered by PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

As they claim in their introduction:

> PHP 5 comes with a complete reflection
>   API that adds the ability to
>   reverse-engineer classes, interfaces,
>   functions, methods and extensions.
>   Additionally, the reflection API
>   offers ways to retrieve doc comments
>   for functions, classes and methods.

Comment: reflection API is rather advanced for new users and has almost no documentation :(

Comment: Well, this sounds like the perfect reason to start writing the doc for it.

Answer (score 1):

- [get_declared_classes()](http://php.net/get_declared_classes)
- [get_class_methods()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)
- [get_class_vars()](http://php.net/get_class_vars)